# 110 connection timeout error while connecting to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, nginx

Actually am using server with nginx,php5 for my website.

Trying to connect DB on another server using `mysqli_connect('host','user','pwd','dbname')`
But it always gives `"110 Connection Timeout Error"`

Also tried to connet it from `command line`, it also gets the same.

Do anyone have some fixes for this?

Comment: I think that the value of host is not correct. Check your db credentials in cpanel of that server.

Comment: Please check the configuration of your MySQL server.

Comment: But it connects from another server. Using the same credentials in new server too..

Answer (score 0):

I think this one should work.
Follow this
https://www.tekovic.com/fixing-timeout-between-nginx-and-php-fpm

Answer (score -1):

**110 Connection Timeout Error:** That means it takes your web server more than 60 seconds to respond.

To solve this problem in **nginx.conf** change the value of `proxy_read_timeout` directive. This directive determines how long nginx will wait to get the response to a request. By default it's 60 seconds. Change it to 300 seconds:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  howtounix.info;

    location / {
        ...
        proxy_read_timeout 300;
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

This should fix the problem.